# Marshalling structure and union from C To c#

Tags: c#, pointers, union, marshalling, unmarshalling

C Code:

```c
struct WbemQualifier {
    CIMSTRING name;/* [relative,charset(UTF16),string] */
    uint8_t flavors;
    enum CIMTYPE_ENUMERATION cimtype;
    union CIMVAR value;/* [switch_is(cimtype)] */
}/* [public,nopull,nopush] */;

struct WbemQualifiers {
    uint32_t count;
    struct WbemQualifier **item;/* [ref] */
}/* [public,nopull,nopush] */;

struct WbemPropertyDesc {
    uint32_t cimtype;
    uint16_t nr;
    uint32_t offset;
    uint32_t depth;
    struct WbemQualifiers qualifiers;
}/* [public] */;

struct WbemProperty {
    CIMSTRING name;/* [relative,charset(UTF16),string] */
    struct WbemPropertyDesc *desc;/* [relative] */
}/* [public] */;

struct CIMSTRINGS {
    uint32_t count;
    CIMSTRING *item;/* [string,charset(UTF16),ref] */
}/* [nopush,nopull,public] */;

/* bitmap DEFAULT_FLAGS */
#define DEFAULT_FLAG_EMPTY ( 1 )
#define DEFAULT_FLAG_INHERITED ( 2 )

struct WbemClass {
    uint8_t u_0;
    CIMSTRING __CLASS;/* [relative,null_is_ffffffff,string,charset(UTF16)] */
    uint32_t data_size;
    struct CIMSTRINGS __DERIVATION;
    struct WbemQualifiers qualifiers;
    uint32_t __PROPERTY_COUNT;
    struct WbemProperty *properties;
    uint8_t *default_flags;
    union CIMVAR *default_values;
}/* [public,flag(LIBNDR_FLAG_NOALIGN),noprint,nopull,nopush] */;

struct WbemMethod {
    CIMSTRING name;/* [null_is_ffffffff,string,charset(UTF16),relative] */
    uint32_t u0;
    uint32_t u1;
    struct WbemQualifiers *qualifiers;/* [relative] */
    struct WbemClassObject *in;/* [relative,subcontext(4)] */
    struct WbemClassObject *out;/* [relative,subcontext(4)] */
}/* [public] */;

struct WbemMethods {
    uint16_t count;
    uint16_t u0;
    struct WbemMethod *method;
}/* [public,flag(LIBNDR_FLAG_NOALIGN)] */;

struct WbemInstance {
    uint8_t u1_0;
    CIMSTRING __CLASS;/* [charset(UTF16),string,relative] */
    uint8_t *default_flags;/* [unique] */
    union CIMVAR *data;/* [unique] */
    uint32_t u2_4;
    uint8_t u3_1;
}/* [flag(LIBNDR_FLAG_NOALIGN),public,nopull,noprint,nopush] */;

struct WbemClassObject {
    uint8_t flags;
    CIMSTRING __SERVER;/* [charset(UTF16),string,ref] */
    CIMSTRING __NAMESPACE;/* [ref,string,charset(UTF16)] */
    struct WbemClass *sup_class;/* [unique] */
    struct WbemMethods *sup_methods;/* [unique] */
    struct WbemClass *obj_class;/* [unique] */
    struct WbemMethods *obj_methods;/* [unique] */
    struct WbemInstance *instance;/* [unique] */
}
```

C# Code:

```cs
private enum CIMTYPE_ENUMERATION
{
    CIM_EMPTY = 0,
    CIM_SINT8 = 16,
    CIM_UINT8 = 17,
    CIM_SINT16 = 2,
    CIM_UINT16 = 18,
    CIM_SINT32 = 3,
    CIM_UINT32 = 19,
    CIM_SINT64 = 20,
    CIM_UINT64 = 21,
    CIM_REAL32 = 4,
    CIM_REAL64 = 5,
    CIM_BOOLEAN = 11,
    CIM_STRING = 8,
    CIM_DATETIME = 101,
    CIM_REFERENCE = 102,
    CIM_CHAR16 = 103,
    CIM_OBJECT = 13,
    CIM_FLAG_ARRAY = 0x2000,
    CIM_ARR_SINT8 = CIM_FLAG_ARRAY | CIM_SINT8,
    CIM_ARR_UINT8 = CIM_FLAG_ARRAY | CIM_UINT8,
    CIM_ARR_SINT16 = CIM_FLAG_ARRAY | CIM_SINT16,
    CIM_ARR_UINT16 = CIM_FLAG_ARRAY | CIM_UINT16,
    CIM_ARR_SINT32 = CIM_FLAG_ARRAY | CIM_SINT32,
    CIM_ARR_UINT32 = CIM_FLAG_ARRAY | CIM_UINT32,
    CIM_ARR_SINT64 = CIM_FLAG_ARRAY | CIM_SINT64,
    CIM_ARR_UINT64 = CIM_FLAG_ARRAY | CIM_UINT64,
    CIM_ARR_REAL32 = CIM_FLAG_ARRAY | CIM_REAL32,
    CIM_ARR_REAL64 = CIM_FLAG_ARRAY | CIM_REAL64,
    CIM_ARR_BOOLEAN = CIM_FLAG_ARRAY | CIM_BOOLEAN,
    CIM_ARR_STRING = CIM_FLAG_ARRAY | CIM_STRING,
    CIM_ARR_DATETIME = CIM_FLAG_ARRAY | CIM_DATETIME,
    CIM_ARR_REFERENCE = CIM_FLAG_ARRAY | CIM_REFERENCE,
    CIM_ARR_CHAR16 = CIM_FLAG_ARRAY | CIM_CHAR16,
    CIM_ARR_OBJECT = CIM_FLAG_ARRAY | CIM_OBJECT,
    CIM_ILLEGAL = 0xfff,
    CIM_TYPEMASK = 0x2FFF
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WbemQualifier
{
    public IntPtr name; /* [relative,string,charset(UTF16)] */
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] public byte flavors;
    public IntPtr cimType;
    public IntPtr value;/* [switch_is(cimtype)] */
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WbemQualifiers
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] public uint count;
    public IntPtr item; //WbemQualifier
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WbemPropertyDesc
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint cimtype;
    ushort nr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint offset;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint depth;
    IntPtr qualifiers; //WbemQualifiers
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct WbemProperty
{
    public IntPtr name;/* [relative,string,charset(UTF16)] */
    public IntPtr desc; //WbemPropertyDesc
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Auto)]
public struct CIMSTRINGS
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public uint count;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)]
    public byte[] item; //String
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WbemMethods
{
    public ushort count;
    public ushort u0;
    public IntPtr method;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WbemInstance
{
    public byte u1_0;
    public IntPtr __CLASS;/* [charset(UTF16),string,relative] */
    public IntPtr default_flags;/* [unique] */
    public IntPtr data;/* [unique] */
    public uint u2_4;
    public byte u3_1;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WbemClass
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public byte u_0;

    public IntPtr __CLASS;/* [charset(UTF16),relative,string,null_is_ffffffff] */

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public uint data_size;

    public IntPtr __DERIVATION; //CIMSTRINGS
    public IntPtr qualifiers; //WbemQualifiers

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    public uint __PROPERTY_COUNT;

    public IntPtr properties; //WbemProperty
    public IntPtr default_flags;
    public IntPtr default_values;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WbemClassObject
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public byte Flags;
    public IntPtr Server;
    public IntPtr Namespace;
    public IntPtr sup_class;
    public IntPtr sup_methods;
    public IntPtr obj_class; //WbemClass
    public IntPtr obj_methods;
    public IntPtr instance;

    public WbemClassObject(int flag)
    {
        this.Flags = 0;
        this.Server = IntPtr.Zero;
        this.Namespace = IntPtr.Zero;
        this.sup_class = IntPtr.Zero;
        this.sup_methods = IntPtr.Zero;
        this.obj_class = IntPtr.Zero;
        this.obj_methods =IntPtr.Zero;
        this.instance = IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
```

When I run the C code, `WbemClassObject` instance set like below picture.

[image]

When I marshal in C#, `u_o`, `__CLASS`, `datasize` members in `obj_class` (`WbemClass` structure) `IntPtr` is coming correctly, but `__DERIVATION` variable that exist later datasize member is setting failure. Similarly, if you look at the pictures, some variables include other variables' value. Interesting...

[image]

[image]

I am implementing on Ubuntu and .Net Core 3.0.

Is there anyone that have an idea?

Comment: The first thing that came up on me while only reading the title is [StructLayoutAttribute.Pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack?view=netframework-4.8). Also are both 32/64bit? Because the size of IntPtr is different between them.

Comment: It's 64 bit @JeroenvanLangen

Comment: Well, starting from the first structure, `WbemQualifier`, you have `enum CIMTYPE_ENUMERATION` member in C which you declare as IntPtr in C#. Are you sure it's pointer-sized in C, and if so, why did you make the enum itself `int` in C#?

Comment: @GSerg, yes you're right, i changed to int. But the error is before from there. Error is  happening, **WbemClassObject** structure and its member **WbemClass obj_class** in it.